# Why is my comment feed broken?

Tags: feed

[Here is my site](http://oldmankit.com). According to the WordPress codex, my comments feed should be [http://oldmankit.com/comments/feed/](http://oldmankit.com/comments/feed). Indeed, every post has that link in its header.  However, it's broken. If you click on that link, you'll see that loading it returns a completely blank page.

My first question is, can anyone help me work out why it's broken?

Second, is there a good reason to keep the comments feed? Obviously the posts feed is important for a blog, but a *comments* feed?

Comment: You comment feed link works fine.

Comment: Your page source is showing the right link though I, even can't get access to your comment feed. Can't understand why? Please make sure, your `functions.php` consists a code like this: `add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );`

Comment: Does any post on your site actually *have* any comments? It can't show them if it doesn't have anything to show.

Comment: I'm embarassed to say that @Otto is right. I had a complete overhaul of the site (after getting hacked) and lost all the comments as I built the database from scratch. I just put one up and yes, now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "feed" is just another view of the site, really. If there's no matching items, then you'll get a 404 and an empty "view". This view can be expressed as a "no items found" on the front end of the site, while it will be an empty feed if looking at a feed view.

Since you had no comments, the query matched nothing, resulting in a 404 header status and an empty feed (which was a correct feed and viewable if you did a view-source on it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were no comments on the whole site. Adding a comment resolved the problem.

(Thanks to @Otto for this answer.)

Comment: That's peculiar behavior... I would expect feed with no items rather than 404.

Comment: It doesn't actually display a 404 page, but I found the problem when using Xenu link sleuth, which detects 404s I think. (I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Rarst Any main query which results in no results causes a 404 status header to be set. It will still produce a normal empty feed for the content, but the status of the page will be 404. If this was not a feed request, then it would also set is_404 and cause the theme to load the 404.php file.

Comment: That's weird, because I actually got front-end 404 when checking out feed link in question back then. Never mind, probably some glitch...